# What happens when calling start() on a thread several times

Tags: java, multithreading

If I call `start()` on thread A, causing it to run, and then call `start()` again while it's still running, what happens?

Example:

```
myThread.start();

// myThread is running...  

myThread.start();
```

Comment: You could just try and see for yourself.

Comment: What happened when you tried it once? What did you find when you looked it up in the Javadoc? Zero research. -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [IllegalThreadState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalThreadStateException.html) exception will be thrown. There is no way to get a thread back to the "waiting to be started" state after it has been started, so whatever the state the thread is in after the first `start`, it will be in the wrong state for the second one.

Comment: if i want to restart the thread how can do ? i call interrupt on thread and check it on the thread run method to exit , and recall start ? and if the thread isn't terminate ?

Comment: @dariofrongi: That's a bad idea. Code the thread to do what you want to do in the first place so you don't have to mess with it. If you interrupt it and it holds a lock the thread that resumes it needs, you'll deadlock.

Comment: i have to implement a thread that in his constructor takes a bluetooth device and in the run method it try to connect whit this device, but if in the main thread while the bleutooth thread is running the user click again on connect and choose another bluetooth device, i want to stop bluetooth thread and run it again with the new device, hoow can do it ?

Comment: @dariofrongi: Leave that thread alone and create a new thread.

Comment: yes but to terminate this thread call interrupt and check it on run method ?

Comment: Code the thread to terminate when it should terminate so you don't have to reach in from the outside and push it around. (For example, when the constructor returns, you can test if the user changed the device and if so, then terminate.) If you feel you have to push a thread around from the outside, that should immediately tell you that you wrote the code the thread is running wrong. If you wrote it right, it would be doing what you want it to do without you having to make it.

Comment: i dont undeerstand what i have to do... user choose device A... i create the thread with argument A... during the comunication user choose B,... so the program have to terminate thread and create another thread with argument B... how ? sorry but i cant understand very well english

Comment: @dariofrongi: Create another thread with argument B. And code the thread so that if the argument changes, it terminates itself at the first opportunity so you don't have to do anything special to the first thread. (You may need to wait for the first thread to terminate before launching the second, it depends on your design. If you must do that, then do that. Code the thread to terminate as soon as possible if it's no longer needed. But do it in the thread, do not "reach in" from the outside.)